# How to seed database in zend framework 3 (doctrine/migrations)?

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework3

I'm creating migration like below. I couldn't find a way to seed db.
Looking for something similar db:seed in laravel ?

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $table = $schema->createTable('user_map');
    $table->addColumn('id', 'integer', ['autoincrement'=>true]); 
    $table->addColumn('user_id', 'integer', ['notnull'=>true]);
    $table->addColumn('relation_id', 'integer', ['notnull'=>true]);
    $table->setPrimaryKey(['id']);
    $table->addOption('engine' , 'InnoDB');       
}
```

Comment: Are you using a `config/cli-config.php` file to run your migration in standalone, or are you using something else for your doctrine-migrations integration? Also have you looked at https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to insert data in the table created at your migration is to do it in the **postUp()** method. Just add in your migration class:

```
public function postUp(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->connection->insert('user_map', array(
        'user_id' => 1,
        'relation_id' => 2
    ));
    parent::postUp($schema);
}
```

[Zend 3 migrations documentation](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Database_Migrations/Creating_Migrations.html)